# How to pause and unpause thread in a game?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new in developing games, i trying to develop a simple shooting space game and everything works perfect. now, i want to create a Dialog popup when the user click on the back button and the game should pause until the user press resume. the game is paused but when i click the resume button the game still on pause here is my game Loop class:

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements Runnable , SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public static  MyPreferences pref;
    public static Levels level;
    public static int SCREEN_W;
    public static int SCREEN_H;
    public static  boolean running;
    private static Thread thread = null;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint p = new Paint();
    public static Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static Resources res;
    public static Timer timer;






    public Game(Context context) {
        super(context);
        res = getResources();
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        level = new Levels();
        timer = new Timer();
        pref = new MyPreferences(context);
        System.out.println("Create Game instance");

    }



    public void run() {
        init();

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double delta = 0;
        double ns = 1000000000.0 / 30.0;

        System.out.println("Run method" + running);
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+=(now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){continue;}

            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            SCREEN_W = canvas.getWidth();
            SCREEN_H= canvas.getHeight();

            while (delta >-1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }

            level.level1();
            render(canvas); 
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


            if(ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER <=0){
                System.out.println("Loose!");
                ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER  = 100;
                stop();
                start();
            }
        }
    }



    private void render(Canvas c) {
        handler.render(c);
        textOnScreen(c);
    }


    public void tick(){
        handler.tick();
    }


    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Init game...");
        ControlPanel.COINS = pref.getInt("coins");
        MainActivity.music.backgroundMusic();
        handler.addSpaceShip(new Player(500, 500, 10, 10, handler, Sprite.getSprite(0)));

//      handler.addKing(new King(Game.SCREEN_W / 2, 100,
//              40, 40, handler, Sprite.getSprite(18), 0));
    }



    public  void start() {
        if(thread==null){
        System.out.println("Start thread");
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();     

        timer.start();
        }
        if(!running)    running = true;
        System.out.println("Running = " + running);
    }


    public static  void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stop thread");
        running = false;
        timer.stop();
        pref.putInt("coins", ControlPanel.COINS);
        System.out.println("Running = " + running);
    }






    public  void destroyed() {
        System.out.println("Stop");
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join(300);
            thread.interrupt();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void textOnScreen(Canvas c){
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        p.setTextSize(50);
        c.drawText("POWER = " + ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER, SCREEN_W / 2 ,50 , p);
        c.drawText("Time = " + timer.timeFormat(), 100  ,50 , p);
        c.drawText("Coins = " + ControlPanel.COINS, 10 ,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawText("Bullets = " +ControlPanel.BULLET, SCREEN_W - 390,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawText(ControlPanel.Distance + " km ", SCREEN_W  /2  - 200,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
    }







    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
System.out.println("###surface created!");

    }







    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        System.out.println("###surface Changed!");

    }







    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        System.out.println("###surface Destroid!");

    }
}
```

and here is my Dialog class:

```
public class DialogPause extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button btn;

    public DialogPause(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.pause_game);
        Game.running = false;

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.resume){
    Game.running = true;

    this.dismiss();
}
    }
}
```

and my MainActivity class:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    public Game game;
    public static Music music;


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        music = new Music(this);
        game = new Game(this);
        game.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(game);

    }




    protected void onStart() {
    game.start();
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        music.StopBackgroundMusic();
        game.destroyed();
        super.onStop();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new DialogPause(this).show();
    }




    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            //the x and y point 
            float x  = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            //The w and h of the space ship
            int spaceShipW = Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).getSprite().getWidth();
            int spaceShipH = Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).getSprite().getWidth();

            //Moving 
            if( x > 10 || x > Game.SCREEN_W - spaceShipW ){
                Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).setX((int) x - (spaceShipW / 2) - 64);
                Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).setY((int) y -  (spaceShipH +200) );
            }

            //Shooting
            Bullet.shoot(y, x);

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                //Change sprite image when click
                Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).getSprite().setWhatColumnX(0);
                Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).getSprite().setFramesToAnimate(2);

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                //Change sprite image when release
                Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).getSprite().setWhatColumnX(1);
                Game.handler.spaceShip.get(0).getSprite().setFramesToAnimate(0);

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { 

        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

By the way i will like to hear more opinions of my game loop code I created because I have sometimes crashes when I exit the game.

and how can i use some asyncTask when the game is finished to load because it's take a 4 sec until the game is load.
**Thanks to all who help me I am very appreciate it!**

Comment: I suggest to use LibGDX game engine. don't reinvent the wheel. It's one of the best game engine I've ever seen for android (Simple, Compact). It has the render loop, openGL drawing surface and many other great features. And outputs for multi platform (Android, Windows, OSX, IOS, html). And for  the question, define the dialog inside the loop.

Comment: In "LibGDX" There will be things that I can not do native in Java?

Comment: @Anna LibGDX is an API that uses java (I think you can also use SCALA). Everything would be the same, but there would be methods for you to use (i.e. game loop, game frames, draw, sprite loaders, etc.).

Comment: Actually you can do whatever you can do in both of them, but LibGDX provides most of the things essential for game programming so you don't need to rewrite them. But one thing native java can't do is outputting for different platforms while LibGDX output for Android, ios and other platforms as well, which is very important especially for game programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a boolean value `paused` and whenever the back button is pressed toggle the value (`paused = !paused;`)

And in you loop before you call tick add a condition:

```
if(!paused) tick();
```

It's better to simply not mess with the thread.

Comment: Thank's but why when i changed  the "running" it doesn't worked?

Comment: @Anna changing the running variable would cause the main thread to terminate and subsequently all other threads. Basically the program would end.

Comment: Oh, right thank you alot! very helpful information! you know something about my other question?

Comment: About you're game loop?

Comment: yes and abput using asyncTask to handle the game loading with a splash Screen

Comment: @Anna You're game loop is working but somewhat disorganized. I suggest looking at some example code online to understand the workflow of games. For example, generally the tick (update) method in the game class loops through an array of game objects and calls their own tick method. The timer would work asynchronously, but I personally like managing my own timers with longs and the system time to avoid threading. This makes the code messier a hard to write but also avoids threading, which is difficult as well.

Comment: like i said i little bit new with develop game. what do you think the best way to create a menu screen to my game?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71637/discussion-between-anna-and-dando18).